How to set up GraphServiceClient with AcquireTokenInteractive in ASP.NET MVC app
I want to use GraphServiceClient in an ASP.NET MVC application following this example.
Due to some great help I got for my question, I was able to get to a point, where I need to add AcquireTokenInteractive in order to fix the following error (suggested here)

MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call

The DI is set up like this:
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))                 
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

For test purposes I put this code into the HomeController:
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _logger = logger;

    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    usrAsync();
}

async Task usrAsync()
{
    var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
    //The above line throws the MsalUiRequiredException 
}

How can I set up AcquireTokenInteractive?
I use the following packages:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi" Version="2.15.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.15.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.15.2" />


You have a race condition

Does the code below you required? There's no AcquireTokenInteractive in the document you shared, but based on the method name, it looks like to be used for obtaining access token. Since you already had .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes), so that you could inject ITokenAcquisition  into your controller then use it to generate access token.
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

    public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
    {
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "api://xxx/Tiny.Read" });
    }
}

My Sample below would generate access token for custom API scope, if you want to generate token for Graph API, you can use scope like new string[] { "User.Read", "Mail.Read" }. By the way, since you are using Graph SDK now, you don't need to generate access token for calling Graph API, just using the SDK.
==========================================
all my codes in a new MVC app created by VS template and choosing Microsoft Identith platform as authentication type
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
                        //.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
{
    ExceptionHandler = async ctx => {
        var feature = ctx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        if (feature?.Error is MsalUiRequiredException
            or { InnerException: MsalUiRequiredException }
            or { InnerException.InnerException: MsalUiRequiredException })
        {
            ctx.Response.Cookies.Delete($"{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix}{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}");
            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery());
        }
    }
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

appsettings.json
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "ClientId",
  "ClientSecret": "ClientSecret",
  "Domain": "TenantId",
  "TenantId": "TenantId",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
"Graph": {
  "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
  "Scopes": "user.read"
},

My Controller:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebMvcGraphV5.Models;
using static System.Formats.Asn1.AsnWriter;

namespace WebMvcGraphV5.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
        {
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
        {
            var me = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
            return View();
        }
    }
}

Packages I used:
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi" Version="2.15.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.15.2" />
</ItemGroup>

